# jquery autocomplete input field nothing happens

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, autocomplete

I want to implement one autocomplete input field but when I start to insert some text nothing happens, for one sec the "busy circle" shows up and that is all.
Here is my code:
html>

```
<div class="products-inv"><?php echo $product_name  ?></div>
<input type="text" id="product_name" name="product_name" />
```

the first div is test for displaying the php variable value what shows up well

jquery>

```
jQuery( function() {
function log( message ) {
  jQuery( "<div>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" );
  jQuery( "#log" ).scrollTop( 0 );
}

jQuery( "#product_name" ).autocomplete({
  source: "../route/to/search.php",
  minLength: 2,
  select: function( event, ui ) {
    log( "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id );
  }
});
```

} );

and the search.php file content>

```
$query = 'database data';
```

$db->setQuery( $query );

$product_name = $db->loadResult();

the error console is empty.

thanks in advice

Comment: Echo the $product_name in the php file at the end.As it is you dont get anything from it

Comment: your search.php code?

Comment: Nothing in input field, only I get displayed the first value of product second time, after the <?php echo $product_name  ?>

Comment: search php code:   $query = 'database data';
$db->setQuery( $query );

$product_name = $db->loadResult();

Answer (score 0):

**your server side code does not return the data expected by the plugin.**

From the documentations of the [jQuery autocomplete plugin](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source) about the **source** option

> When a string is used, the Autocomplete plugin expects that string to
>   point to a URL resource that will return JSON data

your `search.php` script must return the items you want to suggest to the user (show up in the autocomplete list )

that is an example:

```
/*term is a parameter generated by the plugin and contains
 the string the user has typed in the input*/

$_GET['term'] = isset($_GET['term']) ? $_GET['term'] : null;

//manage your own query depending on your database and preferred way for db interactions
//$query = "select product_name from product where product_name like ?";
//$term = "%{$_GET['term']}%";
//$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
//$stmt->bind_param("s", $term);
//$stmt->execute();
//$result = $stmt->get_result();
$autocompleteList = [];
while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
     $autocompleteList[] =  $row['product_name'];        
}
die(json_encode($autocompleteList));
```